# Wordpress: Display Particular Div Only If Post Was Published Today

Tags: php, wordpress, post, blogs

I am creating a deals type website with one deal per day type thing using Wordpress. Basically I am trying to show a sponsor image for today's deal only based on the condition that if today's post date is the same as the server, then show the sponsor div and image, otherwise don't show it.

I could have sworn the following code worked, but now doesn't appear to work at all:

```
if( date('Yz') == get_the_time('Yz') ):
```

Any help and thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: What does `get_the_time('Yz')` output?

Comment: @Pekka: It's just wrapper to PHP's date(): codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate all of your replies guys, but I figured this one out myself eventually. Here is the solution if anyone needs it, I am sure it could be better, but it works the way I want it too.

```
<?php
    $postDate = strtotime( $post->post_date );  
    $todaysDate = time();
    if( $postDate >= $todaysDate ):
        // Do some stuff for todays post
    endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might just be a case of it not working outside the loop.